# Access the a action payload after switchmap(api call) in ngrx Effect

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

```
 saveQuiz$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(quizActions.addQuiz),
      map(action => action.saveQuiz),
      switchMap((quiz) => this.quizDataService.postQuiz(quiz)),
      tap((quizId) => console.log('NEED THE ACTION PAYLOAD HERE')),
      map((quizId:number) => quizActions.addQuizSuccess({quiz:{ id:quizId }})),
      catchError(() => EMPTY)
    )
  );
```

This the effect that i created , the issue is i need to access the `action.payload` after the `switchmap (which calls the api)`. Is there any way i can do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
import { combineLatest, of } from 'rxjs';
.....
saveQuiz$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(quizActions.addQuiz),
      map(action => action.saveQuiz),
      switchMap((quiz) => { return combineLatest(of(quiz), this.quizDataService.postQuiz(quiz)); }),
      tap(([quizAction, quizId]) => console.log(`${quizAction}, ${quizId}`)),
      map(([, quizId]) => quizActions.addQuizSuccess({quiz:{ id:quizId }})),
      catchError(() => EMPTY)
    )
  );
```